# Launching and Editing Program with COleDispatchDriver MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, com, mfc

I want to know whether it is possible to edit an external program after launching it from a MFC Dialog. I want to launch an exe and I want to load a database (which is an access file) to the launched program.
I googled this but I found the solutions bit more complex. I have never used COM objects before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: COleDispatchDriver is just a wrapper class around IDispatch, whether you can do what you want depends on whether the external program implemented what you want and exposed its control interface via IDispatch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sheng. Could you provide me an example?