# Call CreateDispatch from a dll gives m_lpDispatch as NULL

Tags: com, mfc, automation, visual-c++-2008

I have a program where I call an exe from a COleDispatchDriver. This gives the m_lpDispatch pointer as NULL. I am calling this from a dll from the main exe. I have added CoInitialize(NULL)/CoUninitialize() to the beginning and end of the code. But still the exe does not show up.

> CoInitialize(NULL);

```
matProp = IMatProp();
matProp.CreateDispatch(_T("MatProp.Document"));
matProp.Initialize();
matProp.ShowApplication( SW_SHOW );
CoUninitialize();
```

IMatProp is the machine generated IDispatch wrapper class which subclasses ColeDispatchDriver class.
And below is the methods of that class.

> long IMatProp::Initialize()
>   {

```
long result;
InvokeHelper(0x1, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&result, NULL);
return result;
```

}

> long IMatProp::ShowApplication(long show)
>   {

```
long result;
static BYTE parms[] =
    VTS_I4;
InvokeHelper(0x2, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&result, parms,
    show);
return result;
```

}

This worked fine when calling from the exe, but when calling from the dll it gave this problem.
Please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, why don't you write one great question instead of posting bits of your problem - I see [this is the beginning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980685/launching-and-editing-program-with-coledispatchdriver-mfc).

Comment: Hi Roman, I have edited the problem to show the code. Sorry for not asking the whole question once.

Comment: All the methods quoted return execution status, do you check it? If so, what is the error code. If `CreateDispatch` is failing, step into with debugger and see where exactly it is failing internally, and what is `HRESULT` code.

Comment: CreateDispatch is failing because m_lpDispatch pointer is null. I had to manually register the exe using the command prompt with MatProp.exe /RegServer. I am working in Windows 7. Can you explain me what is wrong?

Comment: You don't know why this code is failing because you are not doing any error checking at all.  You'll need to fix that first.

Comment: I thought I have figured out the error. The exe is not get registered even if I run it once manually. Because adding it by the cmd solved the error.Am I wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to initialize OLE instead of just COM. Try using `OleInitialize()` and `OleUninitialize()` instead.

MFC apps can control this with a call to `AfxOleInit()` during `CMFCApp::InitInstance()` but you'll need to look after it yourself if you're using multiple threads.

Comment: thanks snowdude, but it gave a debug assertion as ASSERT(!pState->m_bNeedTerm);    // calling it twice? in oleinit.cpp.

Comment: Are you calling AfxOleInit on the SAME thread you're running your COM code on?

Comment: yes, please correct me if I am wrong, I am quite new to this COM objects. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In your CreateDispatch pass a pointer to a COleException object to catch the actual error code. When you do that what's the value of COleException::m_sc?